# Manhwa where the main character becomes a part of a supervillain team

Tags: story-identification, manga

I can't seem to remember the name or find it, but from what I can remember, the first few chapters feature the main character (MC) escaping a government facility using martial arts he learned. Afterwards, when he escapes, the MC gets picked up by two other supervillains who propose to team up. Sorry if I don't have many details, but I really want to resume/re-read it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You used the term 'supervillains,' so did those characters have superpowers? If so, can you describe them? Also, was the main character a supervillain himself, or did he just team up with supervillains? And were there any superheroes in the story?